# how to play alarm audio once in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, notifications, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

When I try to use alarms to launch voice from my application when it doesn't run in determined times  I face a problem.

The audio still running more than one time as I only want it to run once. But it continuo running until the user stop it which is not suitable for my application behavior.

So, is there a way to make alarm audio file run only once in this time?
If no, is there any other way to do that instead of alarms?

Comment: No , i did not find any solution

Answer (score 0):

Alarm are programmed to be repeated forever. You can't unless you change something in the audio file.